# Ionic Timepicker Default Value

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I have a timepicker, how can I set the default time to be displayed as 10am ?

This field will be displaying the data from database if any, or as a new field to be saved.

Below is my html code

```
<div class="fortimepicker" ion-datetime-picker ng-model="ship.fromtimeValue">{{ship.fromtimeValue| date: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your default time in the angular ng-modal like

```
<div class="fortimepicker" ion-datetime-picker ng-model="fromtimeValue">{{fromtimeValue | date: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"}}</div>
```

and set the ng-model in js like:

```
 $scope.fromtimeValue = new Date("October 13, 2014 10:00:00");//or the default date-time you want set
```

After this if you open the picker it will come with the default time '10:00'

If you want to check the working example i have added your code in the codepen ion-datepicker demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXvWdQ , where you can check the first line which comes with 10:00 as default time

Comment: How can I amend the code into like this?
yyyy-MM-dd 10:00:00am and yyyy-MM-dd 18:00:00PM ?